# Read substrings from a string containing multiplication

Tags: string, fortran, gfortran

I am a scientist programming in Fortran, and I came up with a strange behaviour. In one of my programs I have a string containing several "words", and I want to read all words as substrings. The first word starts with an integer and a wildcard, like "2*something".

When I perform an internal read on that string, I expect to read all wods, but instead, the READ function repeatedly reads the first substring. I do not understand why, nor how to avoid this behaviour.

Below is a minimalist sample program that reproduces this behaviour. I would expect it to read the three substrings and to print "3*a b c" on the screen. Instead, I get "a a a".

What am I doing wrong? Can you please help me and explain what is going on?

I am compiling my programs under GNU/Linux x64 with Gfortran 7.3 (7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04).

```
PROGRAM testread

IMPLICIT NONE
CHARACTER(LEN=1024):: string
CHARACTER(LEN=16):: v1, v2, v3

string="3*a b c"

READ(string,*) v1, v2, v3

PRINT*, v1, v2, v3

END PROGRAM testread
```

Comment: Steve gave you the answer of why you are getting the results you observe.  You might consider using the `index` intrinsic function to split string into substrings.  You can do something like `n = index(string, ' '); v1 = string(1:n-1)`.  I'll leave to you to figure out how to get the other substrings.

Answer (score 5):

You are using list-directed input (the * format specifier). In list-directed input, a number (n) followed by an asterisk means "repeat this item n times", so it is processed as if the input was `a a a b c`. You would need to have as input `'3*a' b c` to get what you want.

I will use this as another opportunity to point out that list-directed I/O is sometimes the wrong choice as its inherent flexibility may not be what you want. That it has rules for things like repeat counts, null values, and undelimited strings is often a surprise to programmers. I also often see programmers complaining that list-directed input did not give an error when expected, because the compiler had an extension or the programmer didn't understand just how liberal the feature can be.

I suggest you pick up a Fortran language reference and carefully read the section on list-directed I/O. You may find you need to use an explicit format or change your program's expectations.

Comment: Thank you very much, that explains my problem. Since I don't know the length of substrings, I cannot use a formatted read. I will embedd each substring into single quotes as a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Following the answer of @SteveLionel, here is the relevant part of the reference on `list-directed sequential READ statements` (in this case, for [Intel Fortran](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-rules-for-list-directed-sequential-read-statements), but you could find it for your specific compiler and it won't be much different).

> A character string does not need delimiting apostrophes or quotation marks if the corresponding I/O list item is of type default character, and the following is true:
>
> The character string does not contain a blank, comma (,), or slash ( / ).
>
> The character string is not continued across a record boundary.
>
> The first nonblank character in the string is not an apostrophe or a quotation mark.
>
> **The leading character is not a string of digits followed by an asterisk.**
>
> A nondelimited character string is terminated by the first blank, comma, slash, or end-of-record encountered. Apostrophes and quotation marks within nondelimited character strings are transferred as is.

In total, there are [4 forms](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-forms-for-sequential-read-statements#4ED52618-1AE1-4835-9012-2043DC5296D3) of sequential read statements in Fortran, and you may choose the option that best fits your need:

1. Formatted Sequential Read:

   To use this you change the `*` to an actual format specifier. If you know the length of the strings at advance, this would be as easy as `'(a3,a2,a2)'`. Or, you could come with a format specifier that matches your data, but this generally demands you knowing the length or format of stuff.
2. Formatted Sequential List-Directed:

   You are currently using this option (the `*` format descriptor). As we already showed you, this kind of I/O comes with a lot of magic and surprising behavior. What is hitting you is the `n*cte` thing, that is interpreted as `n` repetitions of `cte` literal.
   As said by Steve Lionel, you could put quotation marks around the problematic word, so it will be parsed as one-piece. Or, as proposed by @evets, you could split or break your string using the intrinsics [`index`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INDEX-intrinsic.html) or [`scan`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SCAN.html). Another option could be changing your wildcard from asterisk to anything else.
3. Formatted Namelist:

   Well, that could be an option if your data was (or could be) presented in the namelist format, but I really think it's not your case.
4. Unformatted:

   This may not apply to your case because you are reading from a character variable, and [an internal READ statement can only be formatted](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-forms-and-rules-for-internal-read-statements#5027D663-4CE5-42B1-A83F-CE68409EE0D2).

Otherwise, you could split your string by means of a function instead of a I/O operation. There is no intrinsic for this, but you could come with one without much trouble (see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/UFGS4c7UGKg) for reference). As you may have noted already, manipulating strings in fortran is... awkward, at least. There are some libraries out there ([like this](https://github.com/szaghi/StringiFor#auxiliary-methods)) that may be useful if you are doing lots of string stuff in Fortran.